# How do I do a flatMap on spark Dataframe rows depending on conditions of multiple field values?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, flatmap

I need to turn an existing map an existing dataframe's rows to multiple rows.
For example depending on if certain fields in a row equal/notequal each other, I need to create x number of rows for that one existing row.

I was doing some searching and learned about explode but I think it can only take 1 column as an input, so I'm wonder if there's something like a flatmap for Dataframes, or do I need convert Dataframe into a RDD and do flatmap and convert it back to a DataFrame.

I've already tried to make it into a rdd with .rdd but it results in a RDD of Rows, i need to flatMap Rows -> Multiple Rows but unsure how to do that.

If i have a one row with fields [a,b,c,d,e,f,g], one of the transformation might be if a == c then the row maps to 2 new rows, if a!=c then row maps to 6 new rows.

Comment: with an example, show the input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the below way:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import spark.implicits._

val rows = List((10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70), (10, 20, 10, 40, 50, 60, 70))
val inDF = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows).toDF("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
inDF.show()
//  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
//  |  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  f|  g|
//  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
//  | 10| 20| 30| 40| 50| 60| 70|
//  | 10| 20| 10| 40| 50| 60| 70|
//  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

val outDF = inDF.sqlContext.createDataFrame(inDF.rdd.flatMap {
  case row if row.getInt(0) == row.get(2) => List(row, row)
  case row if row.getInt(0) != row.get(2) => List(row, row, row, row, row, row)
}, inDF.schema)
outDF.show()
//  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
//  |  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  f|  g|
//  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
//  | 10| 20| 30| 40| 50| 60| 70|
//  | 10| 20| 30| 40| 50| 60| 70|
//  | 10| 20| 30| 40| 50| 60| 70|
//  | 10| 20| 30| 40| 50| 60| 70|
//  | 10| 20| 30| 40| 50| 60| 70|
//  | 10| 20| 30| 40| 50| 60| 70|
//  | 10| 20| 10| 40| 50| 60| 70|
//  | 10| 20| 10| 40| 50| 60| 70|
//  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score -2):

I recommend to make a pandas dataframe with .toPands() function and do whatever you want!

Comment: This doesn't help the questioner as their using scala.

Comment: What @tjheslin1 said, and even in pyspark not recommended because .toPandas would do a collect